# Is it possible to pass the Reactor Context to a Flux created from a Sinks?

Tags: java, project-reactor

We're currrently using the  ReactiveSecurityContextHolder which gets our correct Auth details and is used along the Flux stream.

Now we want to de-couple stuff. The first iteration is that we use a Sinks as an intermediate 'event-hub'. So from an endpoint we produce some item to the Sinks.Many.

A listener is consuming events from this Sinks and doing the heavy work. Now in this consumer I'd like to use the context which is available on the producing site.  I know one can do `deferContextual` to pass on the current context to another Flux. But is it possible to pass the context to the resulting Flux from the Sinks?

Thanks in advance.

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API that exposes that on arbitrary `Sinks`. The challenge with `Sinks` is that a lot of them are multicasting to multiple `Subscriber`s, and the `Context` is defined on each `Subscriber`.

There is a hack though: `Sinks.Many<T>` is `Scannable`, and most concrete implementations *should* expose their current collection of subscribers through the `Stream<Scannable> inners()` method. In the case of a unicast sink, `scan(Attr.ACTUAL)` would also work.

Two big caveats:

- these APIs only expose `Scannable`s, which doesn't allow access to `Context` directly
- if the implementation's inner subscriber isn't `Scannable`, it is replaced in the stream by the `Scannable#NOT_SCANNABLE` constant

Most if not all of `reactor-core` `CoreSubscribers` *are* `Scannable`, but if you connect a custom subscriber which isn't Scannable, even though it has a `Context`, you won't be able to see it.

Multicast Sinks in reactor-core tend to wrap downstream subscribers in their own inner Scannable inner tracker, which would make this approach work.

Unicast Sinks are a bit different as they directly attach to the downstream `Subscriber`. So if it is a `CoreSubscriber` but somehow not a `Scannable`, you won't be able to see it as a `CoreSubscriber` and access its `Context`.

To sum up the approach:

1. call `sink.inners()` to get a `Stream<Scannable>`
2. ensure values are instances of `CoreSubscriber` (that's the part where things can go wrong)
3. cast values to `CoreSubscriber` and call `currentContext()`
4. somehow reconcile the various `Context`s you got to extract the relevant key-value pair(s)

Comment: Option 4 turned out to be the most suitable for us.

Comment: these are steps, not distinct options :)